# how do you set a max-age for javascript/css?

Tags: javascript, css, http

I just ran [Pagetest](http://webpagetest.org/) and it says I need to set a max-age for my JS/CSS. How do I do that?

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like it's talking about HTTP headers. Basically you'll need to add a couple of HTTP headers to be sent with your Javascript and CSS files (and images too, would be a good idea), looking something like this:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Expires: Sat, 28 Mar 2009 16:00:00 GMT
```

The first one gives the maximum amount of time, in seconds, that a browser will keep the content (the JS or CSS file) before downloading it again from the server; the second one gives the date and time after which the browser should redownload the content. Yes, these are two ways of saying the same thing, but the `Cache-Control` header is a little newer and I'm not sure if it's universally supported yet; there's really no harm in specifying both. (`Cache-Control` takes precedence over `Expires` if there is a conflict.)

As for how you actually configure your server to send these headers: it depends on which web server you're running. If you're using Apache, look at [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html).

Answer (score 0):

Every request made to the server (for images, CSS is also included) is made separately.  Deploying the event handlers in the global.asax can allow you to listen to those requests, so there you can modify the response headers and add additional settings you need.

Here are the various events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication_events(v=vs.71).aspx

HTH.